# weird output when parsing csv file

Tags: csv, go, encoding, utf-16

I'm parsing a csv file from google api with golang, the file is encoded in utf-16, code below try to read one record(skip header) and print the record, but it gives me the output like this which is weird:

```
, v=/09/20 00:35:42 k=Smartfren Andromax AD681H
```

I guess it's probably related with utf-16 encoding, but don't know the detail, here is the code:
    package main

```
import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

var url = "http://storage.googleapis.com/play_public/supported_devices.csv"

func main() {

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    r := csv.NewReader(resp.Body)
    r.LazyQuotes = true
    r.FieldsPerRecord = -1
    // skip header
    r.Read()

    m := make(map[string]string)
    for {
        record, err := r.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        if len(record) >= 4 {
            m[strings.TrimSpace(record[3])] = strings.TrimSpace(record[1])
            for k, v := range m {
                log.Printf("k=%s, v=%s\n", k, v)
            }
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you suspected, the input data must be transformed from a stream of UTF-16 encoded characters to UTF-8 encoded ones. You can do that by using the Go sub-repository package [`golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode"
)

var url = "http://storage.googleapis.com/play_public/supported_devices.csv"

func main() {

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    dec := unicode.UTF16(unicode.LittleEndian, unicode.UseBOM).NewDecoder()
    reader := dec.Reader(resp.Body)

    r := csv.NewReader(reader)
    r.LazyQuotes = true
    r.FieldsPerRecord = -1
    // skip header
    r.Read()

    m := make(map[string]string)
    for {
        record, err := r.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        if len(record) >= 4 {
            m[strings.TrimSpace(record[3])] = strings.TrimSpace(record[1])
            for k, v := range m {
                log.Printf("k=%s, v=%s\n", k, v)
            }
            break
        }
    }
}
```